# gdata-python-api + Analytics with simple auth

Tags: python, api, oauth

I'm working on converting a Python script using the Google gdata API client + user/pass authentication to something more suitable for production (an API key). I am pretty frustrated with the muddled state of their documentation on authentication. I admittedly don't have a great grasp of OAuth2, but it seems like it's way more complicated for my usage case, which is: Hit Google Analytics every 24 hours to get the X most popular articles on our site.

In this scenario, we're not dealing with modifying someone's personal data, and all activity is centered on one account. It doesn't seem like OAuth2 is worth the complexity for something so simple.

I see that on the Google API Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/), I've registered there and notice that there's a "Simple API Access" section with one key beneath the "Client ID for web applications" (which appears to be OAuth2). There's also the Google domain update page, https://www.google.com/accounts/UpdateDomain, but that appears to be OAuth related.

Is there any way to use this Simple API Access key (not OAuth) for retrieving analytics data with the Python gdata client, and if so, does anyone have any authentication examples? I already have the data retrieval stuff working once authenticated, but I'm using the user/pass approach, which is not appropriate for production.

Comment: I agree this is really frustrating, I'm in the same boat now.  The use case of OAuth2 doesn't really make sense if you are only using your own data and don't need to authenticate with user accounts.  So I'm confused as well on why they are moving lots of apis over.  From what I understand OAuth1 works without this idea of a callback url?  I would prefer to use the simple api key as well, but it's unclear if this has been deprecated and on which api's.  Lets hope google gets this fixed soon!

Comment: It has been 6 months since this question, anyone found an answer? I just asked 2 very similar questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263776/how-to-use-oauth-with-google-calendar-to-access-only-one-calendar and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270994/how-do-i-use-googles-simple-api-access-key-to-access-google-calendar-info-ph  and my issue is the same : I don't need to access someone else calendar, I need to access only ONE. So the Developper Key should be the way to go but I can't find ANY tutorials onlines or examples. Can someone help?

Comment: I have also tried the simple https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXX-1/profiles?pp=1&key={YOUR-KEY-HERE} with zero success.  I think you need OAuth even if it's your own data =( . I would love to see a solution to this question

Comment: In case you are interested in a working example for OAuth2 with Python and its documentation have a look here:http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/oauth2-google-api-python-google-analytics/. It is not that complicated, provided a clear explanation is available. In case you want to skip user authentication step, your best option is 2-legged-OAuth by means of a "Service Application" - that will get clear after you worked through the usual OAuth2 process.

Answer (score 12):

Greg,

If you are already using the library [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/checkout), this is relatively easy to do if you are the only user that your application will be authorizing.

The general mechanisms were detailed in a [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/09/python-oauth-20-google-data-apis.html) in September, 2011, but I'll describe them here for completeness.

**Part 1**: Go to the [APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and start a new project.

**Part 2**: From the project, go to "Services" and enable "Analytics API"

**Part 3**: From the project, go to "API Access" and click "Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID..." (you'll need to provide a product name, though the value you provide won't matter). When asked for the application type, select "Installed Application" and then "Create client ID". Since you will be the only user, you will only need one refresh token, and you can get this by authorizing from a desktop application a single time.

**Part 4**: Get your client id and client secret from the APIs console and then create an empty token:

```
import gdata.gauth

CLIENT_ID = 'id-from-apis-console'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'secret-from-apis-console'
SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/'  # Default scope for analytics

token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, 
    scope=SCOPE,
    user_agent='application-name-goes-here')
```

I got the scope from [GData FAQ](https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#AuthScopes), though I'm not sure if it is correct.

**Part 5**: Use the token to create authorization URL for you to visit:

```
url = token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
```

Since your application is an "Installed Application", your redirect URI is the default `'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'`. (Also note, the blog post had a typo and used the keyword argument `redirect_url`.)

**Part 6**: Visit the url and authorize your application to make requests on behalf of your account. After authorizing, you'll be redirected to a page with a code on it. This code will be used to exchange for an access token and a long-lived refresh token. The code has a life of 10 minutes and the access token has a life of an hour. The refresh token will allow you to get new access tokens for signing requests in perpetuity (or until you [revoke](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) the permission from your account).

**Part 7**: Use the code to get an access token:

```
code = 'random-string-from-redirected-page'
token.get_access_token(code)  # This returns the token, but also changes the state
```

This again differs slightly from the blog post, because we are using an installed application.

**Part 8**: With the token you can now make all requests you want to make to the analytics client:

```
import gdata.analytics.client

client = gdata.analytics.client.AnalyticsClient()
token.authorize(client)
```

This is the big money right here. When an access token expires, the API requests signed with that token are rejected. However, by authorizing the client as above, when the said requests fail, the `token` attempts to use the refresh token to obtain a new access token. If it successfully obtains a new access token, the client resends the original API request, signed with the new access token.

I don't know anything about the Analytics API so I won't provide any more details there.

**Future Use Note 1**: Saving information for future use. You can re-use this from different places and after this use very easily. There are methods called `token_to_blob` and `token_from_blob` provided by the library that allow turning a token into a string and converting out of a string:

```
saved_blob_string = gdata.gauth.token_to_blob(token)
```

Once you have done this, you can store the string in a file and kill your running Python process. When you'd like to use it again:

```
saved_blob_string = retrieve_string_from_file()  # You'll need to implement this
token = gdata.gauth.token_from_blob(saved_blob_string)
```

**Future Use Note 2**: This token will be able to be used to authorize a client and perform all your magic again and again, so long as you have the refresh token around. If for some reason you would like to get an access token again without calling `token.generate_authorize_url`, you'll need to manually set this on the object:

```
token.redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
```

**Future Use Note 3**: Also, if you lose your refresh token and would like to get another one without having to go to the browser to [revoke](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) the original, you can use the `approval_prompt` parameter to get a new refresh token by visiting the url generated by:

```
url = token.generate_authorize_url(
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
    approval_prompt='force')
```

Comment: I know this was posted a year ago, but I'm going about this process as well and wondering why the 'Sites' API is not listed on the API Console. Is the Sites API not supported?

Comment: There is a difference between GData APIs and Discovery-based APIs. The Sites API is a GData API, while only Discovery-based APIs are in the console. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981641 for some comments about the distinction.