# How do I use Google's "Simple API Access key" to access Google Calendar info (PHP)?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google API v3 to access one google calendar and according to the documentation here : http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#intro and here : https://code.google.com/apis/console/, the solution I need is the "Simple API Access" & "Key for server apps (with IP locking)".

Now, when I create a page with this code :

```
session_start();

require_once 'fnc/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
require_once 'fnc/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php';

$apiClient = new apiClient();
$apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
$service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) {$apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
} else {
    $token = $apiClient->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
}
```

and in my "config.php" file I add ONLY my developper key (in place of the "X") :

```
global $apiConfig;
$apiConfig = array(
    // True if objects should be returned by the service classes.
    // False if associative arrays should be returned (default behavior).
    'use_objects' => false,

    // The application_name is included in the User-Agent HTTP header.
    'application_name' => '',

    // OAuth2 Settings, you can get these keys at https://code.google.com/apis/console
    'oauth2_client_id' => '',
    'oauth2_client_secret' => '',
    'oauth2_redirect_uri' => '',    

    // The developer key, you get this at https://code.google.com/apis/console
    'developer_key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',

    // OAuth1 Settings.
    // If you're using the apiOAuth auth class, it will use these values for the oauth consumer key and secret.
    // See http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html for info on how to obtain those
    'oauth_consumer_key'    => 'anonymous',
    'oauth_consumer_secret' => 'anonymous',
```

But then I get errors and it tells me it's trying to authenticate using the "OAuth 2.0" system which I don't want to use. I only want to access one calendar with an API key.

And amazingly, when I search in google "Simple API Access key" I find nothing, nothing on their docs, no examples, no tutorials, nothing. Am I the only one using this thing?

So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Same here...... Did you manage to get anywhere?

Comment: Out of curiosity - did you add your server's IP to the list of allowed IP addresses under the "Simple API Access" dialogue?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. anyone solved?

Answer (score 5):

(i know this is an old question but i would've been glad if someone
gave a real answer here so i'm doing it now)

---

I came on the same problem, Simple API access is not well documented (or maybe just not where i searched), but using the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) i found a way to get what i need, which is in fact pretty straightforward. **You don't need specific lib** or anything : it's actually really simple.

In my case i simply needed to search a keyword on G+, so i just had to do a GET request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query={KEYWORD}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Now, for a calendar access ([see here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/)), let's pretend we want to fetch access control rules list. We need to refer to [calendar.acl.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.acl.list) which give us the URI :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR_ID}/acl?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Fill in the blanks, and that's pretty much all you need to do. Get a [server key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) (API Access submenu), store it somewhere in your project and call it within URIs you're requesting.

Comment: And for those who wonder, Simple Access falls under the default bucket, not the signed-in one, which means you're limited to 10k request per day.

Comment: I cannot get it to work. i get `{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}`
if i could solve this login required. I have api key, i'm accessing from the ip i authorized.

Comment: API key will only work with public calendar and public endpoints like events not acl

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access your calendar information using *API Key*. API keys (or simple API acess key) are not authorized tokens and can only be used for some API calls such as a Google search query etc; API keys will not let you access any user specific data, which I am assuming is your objective through this calendar application.

Also, from what I see in your code, you are creating a client object which is going to use OAuth 2.0 authentication and hence you are getting authentication error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing called `Simple API Access key`.

Normally OAuth 2.0 is used for authorization. But since you have your reason not to use it.

- If you want to use OAuth1.0 for authorization. You need an `API key` in `Simple API Access` section on the [API Access](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) page.
- If you want to use username & password login instead of OAuth, you can refer to [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html), but this is not recommanded.

Comment: You say there is no such thing, but then say "get an api key in the simple api access section"?

Comment: Just use "API key" to access. There isn't any key called "Simple API Access key".

Comment: Did you check if the API key is really necessary? I think the information in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth conflicts with https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth, and I was able to query Calendar API v3 without the API key at all, with just the consumer key and secret (OAuth1)

Comment: How do you do this now with the Cloud Console?

Comment: I don't think that's true. See: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/api-keys - "When calling APIs that do not access private user data, you can use simple API keys. These keys are used to authenticate your application for accounting purposes. The Google Developers Console documentation also describes API keys."

Comment: oh well elsewhere they write "Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google+ Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you." https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth so confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I got to this thread when trying to do the same today. Although this is way late, but the answer is YES, there is actually simple API key for those apis that does not need user authorizations, and the official client library support this.

The api library do this by Options, which is key, value pair.

Take the example of get information of a given youtube video, you would use this api: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3#VideosListCall.Do

To use api key, simply make a type that implements the CallOption interface, and let it return the api key:

```
type APIKey struct {
}

func (k *APIKey) Get() (string, string) {
    return "key", "YOU API KEY HERE"
}
```

Then when calling the API, supply the APIKey to it:

```
youtube, err := youtube.New(&http.Client{})
call := youtube.Videos.List("snippet,contentDetails,statistics").Id(id)
rsp, err := call.Do(opt)
```

This way, you can construct the youtube client with the vallina http client, rather than oauth client, and enjoy the simple api key.

The first answer said you can use http GET directly, but then you will need to handle the errors and parse the result yourself.

Comment: edit: The original question is for php, but the answer should apply to all clients, it's the same set of API.

Answer (score -2):

See below link which is helpfull to you. The Google API Client Library enables you to work with Google APIs such as Analytics, Adsense, Google+, Calendar, Moderator, Tasks, or Latitude on your server, in the language of your choice.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Thanks,
Chintu

Comment: This does not answer the question. The Google API Client Library is a nightmare for simple integrations, 3mb of library for a simple hook...