# Still possible to use Google Calendar API with API Key?

Tags: api, oauth, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

It appears as though the current version of the Google Calendar API is v3, which in the past I believe has supported both OAuth and simple API Keys for a JavaScript/Browser implementation.

As of 2/2/17: is it possible to still use the Google Calendar API with an API Key, or is required that any access (even access to a public calendar) to the API go through OAuth2.0?

According to the Google Calendar API, "Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests" (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth), but my API request is opening a public calendar and does not require a sign-in as none of the data is private.

Comment: So what was your approach around this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, it seems that the Google Calendar now needs an authorized tokens to access its own API. It is stated in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#AboutAuthorization) that every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google.

I found here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270994/how-do-i-use-googles-simple-api-access-key-to-access-google-calendar-info-ph) that you cannot access your calendar information using API Key. API keys (or simple API access key) are not authorized tokens and can only be used for some API calls such as a Google search query etc; API keys will not let you access any user specific data, which I am assuming is your objective through this calendar application.

I tried to access a Google calendar request by using an API key, but I get an error **401 "Login Required"**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/primary?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

To verify that the API_KEY is the problem, I try to use it in a Google Maps request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```

And I got here a successful response.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Can Oauth version 1 support Google Calendar API?

Answer (score 2):

To add some additional info. Yes this can be done but the request is [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDAR_PUBLIC_ID]/events?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%5BCALENDAR_PUBLIC_ID%5D/events?key=%5BYOUR_API_KEY%5D)

The public calendar id can be found in your calendar settings where you would find your embed code and the share link to your calendar

Answer (score 1):

You can access calendars events list using **GET** method with url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDAR_PUBLIC_ID]/events&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

You can also add more query params, like maxResult, orderBy etc. according to docs https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: Where can we find the [CALENDAR_PUBLIC_ID] ? I try the https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/calendar/[ID-CHUNK] but gives a 404

Comment: Is this the same thing as the Calendar Id ??