# Proper Method for Google Calendar with PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am working on a website for my organization which will allow users of the website to create/modify/etc room reservations for a number of spaces in our building.

Each room has a Google Calendar which links to several monitors around the building to display what rooms are [un]available. So, my goal was to utilize these calendars by having the website I am creating edit these google calendars. The problem I am having however is that from all the documentation I have been able to find, it looks like you have to prompt each user for Google Log-In. This is what I am trying to avoid. I want individuals to be able to log-in to my website, and then on the backend my website provides the authentication to Google so that they can add/edit/remove events from the aforementioned GCals based on permissions on set on their account.

Can anyone help direct me to the proper documentation? I've found a couple of things through some intensive Google-ing of my own, but I've become extremely confused about what method I should be using.

Any assistance in getting things rolling is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to take the user's Google credentials on your website. And at the backend your server will use those credentials to log in to their Google account ?

Comment: No - I want users to simply be able to log-in to my website with a username and password that goes with my site. And since my Google credentials have access to the Google Calendars in question I'll use my credentials with google and control what rights users have through my website...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the concept that you want is to create a website that writes into your own calendar and not on the users calendar. Exactly what this 3 part tutorial of Sample Web Page for Booking gives:

1. [Part 1: Setting up Google Calendar](http://cornempire.net/2011/12/31/part-1-setting-up-google-calendar/)
2. [Part 2: OAuth2 and Configuring Your ‘Application’ With Google](http://cornempire.net/2012/01/08/part-2-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/)
3. [Part 3: A Sample Web Page For Bookings](http://cornempire.net/2012/01/15/part-3-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/)

This tutorial worked for many like what has been done in this SO post - [How do I connect to the Google Calendar API without the oAuth authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995451/how-do-i-connect-to-the-google-calendar-api-without-the-oauth-authentication).

Comment: That seems close to what I want. However, it's not that I want it to write to My Calendar, there are about 13 calendars which I do not own but have access too that I will be writing to based on the input from different users. I haven't had a chance to look over the documentation you've linked but thank you for the suggestions!