# Accessing Google Calendar without OAuth pop-up

Tags: .net, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, windows-10-iot-core

I am writing Clock application which will run on the Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 running.
I would like to access my Google Calendar and display coming events, but all code I can find needs user to fill-in OAuth screen, what is impossible as device will not have any input (keyboard, mouse atc)
Is it possible to authenticate on the other computer and then get some token, file or whatever to incorporate it into my application, so it can log-in without any pop-ups?

Comment: Do you use Google Calendar API in UWP through REST API?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this documentation on how to [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#perform-google-apps-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority).

In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use [service accounts with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved.

Here's a related SO post which might help: [How do I connect to the Google Calendar API without the oAuth authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995451/how-do-i-connect-to-the-google-calendar-api-without-the-oauth-authentication)

Comment: in other words: go for paid google workspace, to have ability to use service account for mentioned purpose.